# Why is my CSS Class style not applying to specific <li>'s?

Tags: css, wordpress, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my CSS Class style not applying to specific <li>'s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613028/why-is-my-css-class-style-not-applying-to-specific-lis)

Answer: This was a dumb mistake, was using '//' for single line comments instead of wrapping in /**/ (been writing too much javascript lately) Thanks for help, sorry for wasting time.

I cannot figure out why this CSS is not applying only to certain li's..

Here is the CSS: (notice the comments it says what does and doesn't apply - it is strange because the facebook link does recognize the class 'post-face' of the parent li and applies the link color but the actual li is not recognizing the class on the edit or facebook li's but it does on the twitter and comment li with the exact same code)

```
.SL .post .post-det .post-tweet {
    /* DOES APPLY */
    background: url(images/post-tweet-icon.png) no-repeat left 2px;
}
.SL .post .post-det .post-tweet a { color:#008ebc; } /* DOES APPLY */

/* FACEBOOK SHARE ADDON */
.SL .post .post-det .post-face {
    /* THIS DOESN'T APPLY */
    background: url(images/post-tweet-icon.png) no-repeat left 2px;
}
.SL .post .post-det .post-face a { color:#A1A1A0; } /* THIS DOES APPLY */
/* END FACEBOOK SHARE ADDON */

.SL .post .post-det .post-edit {
    /* THIS DOESN'T APPLY */
    background: url(images/post-edit-icon.png) no-repeat left 2px;
}
.SL .post .post-det .post-edit a { color:#ff0000; } /* THIS DOES APPLY */
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!--start of Latest Posts-->
<div class="latest">
<span class="toptitle"><strong>Latest Post</strong></span>

<div id="post-89" class="post indexpost">
<div class="post-head">
 <div class="post-date">July 6, 2011</div>
  <h2><a href="http://website.com/geo/?p=89" title="Permalink to Get in Touch" rel="bookmark">Get in Touch</a></h2>
 </div>
    <div class="post-con"><p>Geothermal Solutions is proud to serve the Ontario geothermal market for over 5 years installing over 2000 residential systems. We work for HVAC contractors across Ontario. </p> 
<p><a href="http://website.com/geo/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/residential.jpeg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-112" title="residential" src="http://website.com/geo/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/residential-300x199.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="199" /></a></p> 
<p>With our knowledge and expertise you can have confidence in the loop that is going into the ground and rely on Geothermal Solutions to have it completed in a timely and professional manner. </p> 
<p>We work for many of the major residential ground source installers in Ontario today which trust us for our reputation and quality work they can depend on.</p> 
</div>
 <ul class="post-det">
    <li class="post-tag"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links"></span> <a href="http://website.com/geo/?tag=geothermal" rel="tag">geothermal</a> | <a href="http://website.com/geo/?tag=geothermal-energy" rel="tag">geothermal energy</a> | <a href="http://website.com/geo/?tag=green-2" rel="tag">green</a> | <a href="http://website.com/geo/?tag=residential" rel="tag">residential</a></li>
    <li class="post-comment"><a href="http://website.com/geo/?p=89#respond" title="Comment on Get in Touch">Leave a comment</a></li>
<li class="post-tweet"><a href='http://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='http://website.com/geo/?p=89' data-text='Get in Touch' data-count='vertical'>Tweet This !</a></li>

  <li class="post-face"><a href='http://facebook.com' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='http://website.com/geo/?p=89' data-text='Get in Touch' data-count='vertical'>Share This !</a></li>  
  <li class="post-edit"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://website.com/geo/wp-admin/post.php?post=89&amp;action=edit" title="Edit Post">Edit</a></li>  </ul>
 </div>
<!--End of Post -->

</div>
<!--end of Latest Posts-->
```

Comment: [What's with the double post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613028/why-is-my-css-class-style-not-applying-to-specific-lis)

Comment: Sorry I'm new here.. I thought no one was responding because of all the bad formatting on the question, so I reposted with proper question format.

Comment: You should edit the original question like you did earlier.

Comment: Do those images exist? Is there anything else setting background to those LIs? You should check this with Firebug and it should become obvious very quickly.

Comment: I have checked with developer tools, nothing else sets background image, the style is not being set then overwritten, it's not even being set in the first place. the li does not get the .post-face at all, however the a within the li does get styled through the .post-face so for some reason the li is recognized as .post-face for the a but not the actual li itself.. can you look through firebug and see if you see the error? http://bvibrantdesign.com/geo/

Comment: BoltClock - how do I flag as double for deletion? it won't let me delete due to having answers.

Comment: BoltClock? Can moderators edit my question? I figured out the problem and it turns out no one on here would have been able to answer it because somehow my CSS code block got edited (formatted better) but it wasn't by me.. I was using // as a CSS comment instead of /**/ and thats what caused this (silly mistake) however, someone edited my code block and changed all the comments to /**/ so no one would have been able to realize what I was doing wrong

Comment: @tsdexter: I was the one who did the edit. I'm sorry about that! I had no idea that you were really using `//` comments in your code and that they'd turn out to be the real problem. You can use the "flag" link next to the edit|delete links, and say it needs moderator attention.

Comment: Yes, I checked the edit history.. And no worries, I appreciated the edit because I'm not used to the syntax for adding code blocks to the questions yet but as I said, it was a dumb mistake I've been writing a lot of javascript plugins lately and forgot there are no single line comments in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.SL .post .post-det .post-tweet {
    /* DOES APPLY */
    background: url(images/post-tweet-icon.png) no-repeat left 2px;
}
.SL .post .post-det .post-tweet a { color:#008ebc; } /* DOES APPLY */

    /* FACEBOOK SHARE ADDON */
    .SL .post .post-det li.post-face {
        /* THIS DOESN'T APPLY */
        background: url(images/post-tweet-icon.png) no-repeat left 2px !important;
    }
    .SL .post .post-det .post-face a { color:#A1A1A0; } /* THIS DOES APPLY */
    /* END FACEBOOK SHARE ADDON */

    .SL .post .post-det li.post-edit {
        /* THIS DOESN'T APPLY */
        background: url(images/post-edit-icon.png) no-repeat left 2px !important;
    }
    .SL .post .post-det .post-edit a { color:#ff0000; } /* THIS DOES APPLY */
```

Comment: tried that, didnt' work. But I figured out it was a stupid mistake that no one here would have been able to fix because someone (I assume a moderator) edited my code block (to make it more legible).. I was using the wrong type of CSS comments which messed it up (// instead of /**/). It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything in your CSS file after these lines that sets the background to none? If you have Firebug or Chrome you can see which style is being applied to that element.

Comment: No, but even if I did it would set the background to none on all of the li's but it's only the facebook and edit li's that are not showing their pics, the twitter and comment both work...